# Getting a property from a different widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How can I use a property in a different widget?
I have this code:

**Python file**

```
class Control(ToggleButton):
    width_multiplier = NumericProperty(1)


class MainScreen(StackLayout):
    pass


class HomeControl(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HomeControl().run()
```

**KV file**

```
<Control>:
    size_hint: None,None
    height: '100dp'
    width: self.width_multiplier * self.height + (self.width_multiplier - 1) * spacing
    halign: 'center'

<MainScreen>:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    spacing: '10dp'
    padding: '15dp'

    Control:
        text: 'Button'

    Control:
        text: 'Long Button'
        width_multiplier: 2
```

The width of the `Control` widgets should be `width_multiplier` times the height of the widget plus the spacing between `MainScreen`’s children. How can I use the spacing property of `MainScreen` in the `Control` role?
I'm new to Kivy so it’s probably a silly question but I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can use the **parent** property

```
<Control>:
    size_hint: None,None
    height: '100dp'
    width: self.width_multiplier * self.height + (self.width_multiplier - 1) * self.parent.spacing[0]  <--- 
    halign: 'center'
```

Comment: I had to use `self.parent.spacing[0]` because it's a list. But thanks for the answer nonetheless. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Cool, fixed to **spacing[0]**